# can anybody suggest me how to write script on the below problem?

Tags: shell-script

Can anyone suggest how I can use this step in the script (that I need to take the output of the first command i need to use it second command for all three)?

```
[aaa@build]$ find . -name src
./Port/bit/WE-IN/src
./MI/M-Scripts/Msg/src
./MI/M-Scripts/TT/src
[aaa@build]$ cd ./Port/bit/WE-IN/src
```

Comment: does the second command have to be "cd" or can it be "echo" or some other command? It is just that, cd will change directory, if as you say take first command's output and put in second command (cd) then it would navigate three directories in quick succession, you wouldn't be able to do anything except on the last dir so what is the point?

Comment: in each directory i need to execute few more commands so ...

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is `xargs`. Typically you would use it like this:

```
find . -name src -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 echo {}
```

or for your explicit question:

```
find . -name src -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 cd {}
```

Comment: [aaa@build]$ find . -name src                                                            ./Port/bit/WE-IN/src                                                                              ./MI/M-Scripts/Msg/src                                                                    ./MI/M-Scripts/TT/src                                                                         [aaa@build]$ cd ./Port/bit/WE-IN/src

Comment: What is that comment supposed to show?

Comment: i need the command which can help me to take the output of the find command and that can be used one by one in cd command.

Comment: I have updated my answer to do exactly what you ask in the question. It will apply the "cd" command to all outputs from the find command. I'm not sure why you want to do this, but that is what you asked.

Comment: i need to write a script which can do this all task ...                   [aaa@build BIT-1.0.2]$ find . -name src
./Port/bit/WE-IN/src
./IS/MScripts/Msg/src
./IS/MScripts/TT/src
[aaa@build BIT-1.0.2]$ cd ./MIS/MO-Security-Scripts/Msg/src
[aaa@build src]$ pwd
/home/sab/SM/SMSGW-Rel-1-11-8-35/BIT1.0.2/IS/MOScripts/Msg/src
[aaa@build src]$ export DEVHOME=/home/sab/SM/SM-Rel-1-11-8-35/BIT-1.0.2/IS/M-Scripts/Msg/
[aaa@build src]$ vim built.sh
[aaa@build src]$ sh built.sh

Comment: Then please update your original question on how to write shell scripts, this comment section is not meant to discuss and expand the question like this.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is declare shell function , and pass each result of find to a while loop, which will call that function per directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
function f 
{

  echo "THIS IS " $(pwd)
  ls
}

find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "bin" -printf "%P\n" | while read DIRNAME;
do

  cd $DIRNAME
  f
done
```

Here's a sample run:

```
$ ./findAndFunction.sh                                                                               
THIS IS  /home/xieerqi/bin
autostart-script.sh  c  java  perl  python  README.md  sergrep  shell
```

Comment: i need to write a script which can do this all task ...                   [aaa@build BIT-1.0.2]$ find . -name src
./Port/bit/WE-IN/src
./IS/MScripts/Msg/src
./IS/MScripts/TT/src
[aaa@build BIT-1.0.2]$ cd ./MIS/MO-Security-Scripts/Msg/src
[aaa@build src]$ pwd
/home/sab/SM/SMSGW-Rel-1-11-8-35/BIT1.0.2/IS/MOScripts/Msg/src
[aaa@build src]$ export DEVHOME=/home/sab/SM/SM-Rel-1-11-8-35/BIT-1.0.2/IS/M-Scripts/Msg/
[aaa@build src]$ vim built.sh
[aaa@build src]$ sh built.sh